# SenseNet :: File System Blob

Tags: sensenet

We are trying to create custom blob using the sample provided by Sensenet on wiki http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_create_an_external_blob_provider ,
But we found there is an object not exist “FileSystemChunkReaderStream” so we are not able to continue practicing how to work with blobs.

Can you please share with us this class **FileSystemChunkReaderStream** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the *Reader* and *Writer stream* classes can be found in the *Tests* project along with the file system blob provider sample. Although if you are using the *Community* edition, you'll have to wait a bit for the new release because it is behind the *Enterprise* edition.

In the meantime, please check the wiki link you posted above, I **added the two missing stream classes to the article** so that you can continue with your project.

[How to create an external blob provider](http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_create_an_external_blob_provider)

Comment: Thanks, i check the class **FileSystemChunkWriterStream** i think there is a mistake the constructor take only 2 paramters 
**public FileSystemChunkWriterStream(LocalDiskChunkBlobProvider.LocalDiskChunkBlobProviderData providerData, long fullSize)**
and you pass three paramters
**return new FileSystemChunkWriterStream(providerData, context.Length, GetDirectoryPath(providerData.Id));**

Comment: Thanks, the 3rd parameter (the path) has been removed in the dev version, it is not needed anymore. I'll update the sample in the wiki soon, you can freely remove it in your version.